# Print float('+inf'), float('-inf') and float('NaN') with desired indentation

Tags: python

I have a script for testing some functionality.

In this script, I do something like:

```
for n in range(1000000):
    minVal,maxVal = getMinMax(n)
    print('Test #{}: minVal = {:.40f}, maxVal = {:.40f}'.format(n+1,minVal,maxVal))
```

The function `getMinMax` returns a pair of `float` values.

This includes the values of `float('+inf')`, `float('-inf')` and `float('NaN')`.

I would like to make sure that these values are printed with the same indentation (i.e., 40 digits).

Obviously, I cannot add leading or trailing zeros here because it would look senseless.

So I believe that leading or trailing spaces is pretty much the only sensible option.

Is there any "clever" way to do it in Python?

Executing the following piece of code can explain why it is important to me:

```
from math import pi,exp

a = pi
b = exp(1)
c = float('+inf')
d = float('-inf')
e = float('NaN')

print('Test #{}: minVal = {:.40f}, maxVal = {:.40f}'.format(1,a,b))
print('Test #{}: minVal = {:.40f}, maxVal = {:.40f}'.format(2,a,c))
print('Test #{}: minVal = {:.40f}, maxVal = {:.40f}'.format(3,a,d))
print('Test #{}: minVal = {:.40f}, maxVal = {:.40f}'.format(4,a,e))
print('Test #{}: minVal = {:.40f}, maxVal = {:.40f}'.format(5,b,a))
print('Test #{}: minVal = {:.40f}, maxVal = {:.40f}'.format(6,c,a))
print('Test #{}: minVal = {:.40f}, maxVal = {:.40f}'.format(7,d,a))
print('Test #{}: minVal = {:.40f}, maxVal = {:.40f}'.format(8,e,a))
```

Comment: Do you know anything about the range of the two values? Otherwise the lengths of the two `{:.40f}` could be anything (greater than 42 anyway), and you would need to specify the number of leading/trailing spaces you want in the `inf`/`nan` cases.

Comment: @fuglede: Yes, sorry, the range is between 0 and 1, inclusive. And of course, the 3 "illegal" values that I have explicitly stated in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.40f` formatting options will show *40* digits after the decimal point, so to get the correct indentation you have to add the decimal point and the number of digits in front of the decimal point. In your case you're dealing with values in the range from 0 to 1, so that's just 2 extra characters.

The easiest option would be to use the `>` or `<` format option:

```
>>> # > for leading spaces
>>> print('Test #{}: minVal = {:>42.40f}, maxVal = {:>42.40f}'.format(8,e,a))
Test #8: minVal =                                        nan, maxVal = 3.1415926535897931159979634685441851615906

>>> # < for trailing spaces
>>> print('Test #{}: minVal = {:<42.40f}, maxVal = {:<42.40f}'.format(8,e,a))
Test #8: minVal = nan                                       , maxVal = 3.1415926535897931159979634685441851615906

>>> # Check for matching indentation
>>> print('Test #{}: minVal = {:.40f}, maxVal = {:.40f}'.format(1,a,b))
Test #1: minVal = 3.1415926535897931159979634685441851615906, maxVal = 2.7182818284590450907955982984276488423347
```

Comment: Nice, but it seems that I have a "discrepancy" of 2 digits (I'm guessing - the digit before the decimal point, and the decimal point itself).

Comment: I always have 1 digit before the decimal point. How can I adjust your solution? Just change both occurrences of `40` to `42`?